# Parsing data in Excel with functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that looks like col `A` and I want to split it up eventually with `B`,`C`, & `D`. They are separated by `_`

```
1     A                           B         C         D
2     IJ~ABC_TS~DEF_TP~GHI        IJ~ABC    TS~DEF    TP~GHI
```

I was able to get Col2 by doing this:

```
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("_",A2,1)-1)
```

For the next part, I think the best way to do it is do a combination of the `RIGHT` and `LEFT` function.

How do I use the `RIGHT` function in a way where I find everything to the right of the value of Col2 in Col1?

My final output should look like this:

```
TS~DEF_TP~GHI
```

Once I do this, I want to simply take the same LEFT function on this new value to get the result of col `C`.

I cannot figure out how to do the `RIGHT` function though.

This is my attempt:

```
=RIGHT(A2, SEARCH(B2,A2,1))
```

I get an error though.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using **Text to Columns**?

Comment: I want to have a an excel script where if someone pastes a new dataset in the columns, it will automatically parse the data rather than clicking buttons for Text to Columns. The goal is to make it less manual which a function would accomplish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in B1,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1, "_", REPT(" ", LEN($A1))), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*LEN($A1)+1, LEN($A1)))
```

Fill right for the second and third.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. This works for this scenario. In my actual dataset, there are two columns before `A`. When I write this function, and replace `A` with `C` it doesn't start parsing it from the beginning but rather 2 delims to the right. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. If your column is in C, you need to change everything except for COLUMN(A:A). Thanks!

Comment: looking further into the formula, this is really intuitive and outside the box! thanks for the help @jeeped

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell B1 = FIND("_",A1,1)
Cell C1 = =FIND("_",A1,B1)+B1
Then 
Cell D1 = =MID($A1,1,B1-1)
Cell E1 = =MID($A1,$B1+1,$C1-$B1-1)
Cell F1 = =MID($A1,$C1+1,10)
```

You can then copy the formula down and then Copy from D1 to F100 'Where ever you data stops and then do a PasteSpecial Values to D1 and then you can Delete Columns B and C